# Counter-intuitive date command

Tags: linux, shell, date, time

I've been using `date` in a script in order to add one year to a specific date the following way:

```bsh
date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d "$DATE + 1 year"
```

In this example, `DATE` looks like `2022-05-11 14:20`.

Everything is working well. However it turns out that adding one single year, week, or day works fine, but adding multiples returns a bogus result.

Correct result for a singular year, week, or day:

```
$ date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d "2022-05-11 14:20 +1day"
2022-05-12 15:20:00
$ date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d "2022-05-11 14:20 +1week"
2022-05-18 15:20:00
$ date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d "2022-05-11 14:20 +1year"
2023-05-11 15:20:00
```

Bogus result for adding multiple years, weeks, or days:

```
$ date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d "2022-05-11 14:20 +2days"
2022-05-12 14:20:00
$ date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d "2022-05-11 14:20 +3weeks"
2022-05-18 13:20:00
$ date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d "2022-05-11 14:20 +4years"
2023-05-11 12:20:00
```

The first unit is valid, and the others decrease the hour.

The workaround I've found for my case was to add several times the same unit:

```
$ date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d "2022-05-11 14:20 +1day +1day"
2022-05-13 15:20:00
$ date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d "2022-05-11 14:20 +1week +1week +1week"
2022-06-01 15:20:00
$ date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d "2022-05-11 14:20 +1year +1year +1year +1year"
2026-05-11 15:20:00
```

You may have also noted that what I've called “correct results” also increase the date by one hour.

Has anybody have an explanation about why this isn't working as I would expect?

Best regards.